Yfinance history returns different result each time
I use Yfinance to download historical prices and have found that the function returns different result each time. Is it an error or am I doing something wrong?
import yfinance as yf
msft = yf.Ticker('AAK.ST')
data_1 = msft.history(period="max")
data_2 = msft.history(period="max")

The result differs every time I run the code and below is an example where the first two rows differs but the third is equal.

There are a lot of rows that differs:

Any suggestions why, and how to handle this?

The differences that you are seeing are small and might be rounding errors. The result that you get with the history method are adjusted (which may cause these rounding errors). When I turn off the adjustment the results seem to be consistently the same:
import yfinance as yf
aak = yf.Ticker('AAK.ST')
data_1 = aak.history(period="max", auto_adjust=False)
data_2 = aak.history(period="max", auto_adjust=False)

data_1.iloc[:3, :]
data_2.iloc[:3, :]


Thanks, you are probably right but it is still strange that the rounding error differs each time and that is not only the last decimal.

Looking at what the adjustment seems to do, it includes amongst others the dividends in the stock prices of the past. It looks like it is doing so by keeping the current price as is and then adjusting the historical prices. So perhaps the fluctuations you are seeing is because the current price is changing during market open hours. You can try to verify this by trying the above when markets are closed and checking if the fluctuations remain.
